# How to connect to ftp using Eclipse for PHP Developers?

Tags: php, eclipse

I just want to know how to connect through ftp using Eclipse for PHP Developer.

Answer (score 8):

Eclipse provides FTP support through an FTP [plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-team/target.php). Try going to Help>Install New Software, and add http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon (you can replace "neon" with the Eclipse release you have). From there, you should see the PHP, XML, Web Development, and Remote System Explorer plugins. Installing RSE will give you ftp support.

Answer (score 1):

I use Aptana with Php plugin.
You can add projet with distant server and upload files, compare, ...

Answer (score 0):

Check the remote development environment installation in this link http://www.madirish.net/node/220 , install the libraries specified there , so that u can access the files via ftp directly to your eclipse window

Answer (score 0):

Use the [RSE plugin for eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/TM_and_RSE_FAQ#What_is_the_Target_Management_Project.3F)